# Как создать чат между 3 пользователя бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Создал бот анонимный, чат между 2 юзера бота активно, но хочу добавить ещё один пользователь (определённый пользователь) как это сделать не мог решать,
ЧТО ИМЕННО СДЕЛАТЬ ДЛЯ СОЗДАНИЯ ЧАТА МЕЖДУ 2 СОБЕСЕДНИК И 1 ОПРЕДЕЛЁННОМУ ЮЗЕРУ. Код который внизу работает без проблем но чат только между 2 Собеседник, нужно добавить ещё один определённому пользователя!
Мой код в bot.py

```
elif message.text == '‍ Рандом':
            user_info = db.get_chat()
            chat_two = user_info[0]

            if db.create_chat(message.chat.id, chat_two,) == False:
                db.add_queue(message.chat.id, db.get_gender(message.chat.id))
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Дар ҳоли ҷустуҷӯ, интизор шавед бо нафаре пайваст мешавед!', reply_markup = stop_search())
            else:
                mess = 'Нафаре ёфт шуд ки бо шумо дар алоқа аст суҳбатро оғоз намоед \n Барои қатъи сӯҳбат /stop - ро пахш намоед!'

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, reply_markup = stop_dialog())
                bot.send_message(chat_two, mess, reply_markup = stop_dialog())
```

Код из database.py

```
def get_chat(self):
        with self.connection:
            chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `queue`", ()).fetchmany(1)
            if bool(len(chat)):
                for row in chat:
                    user_info = [row[1], row[2],]
                    return user_info
            else:
                return [0]

    def create_chat(self, chat_one, chat_two,):
        with self.connection:
            if chat_two != 0:
                # Создание чата
                self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM `queue` WHERE `chat_id` = ?", (chat_two,))
                self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `chats` (`chat_one`, `chat_two`) VALUES (?,?,)", (chat_one, chat_two,))
                return True

            else:
                # Становимся в очередь
                return False
    
    def get_active_chat(self, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `chats` WHERE `chat_one` = ?", (chat_id,))
            id_chat = 0
            for row in chat:
                id_chat = row[0]
                chat_info = [row[0], row[2]]
            
            if id_chat == 0:
                chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `chats` WHERE `chat_two` = ?", (chat_id,))
                for row in chat:
                    id_chat = row[0]
                    chat_info = [row[0], row[1]]
                if id_chat == 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    return chat_info
            
            else:
                return chat_info

``
```

Comment: как считаете, уместно будет попросить автора вопроса перевести его на русский язык? ))) Из того, что я понял - автор хочет создать "Чат для троих", только зачем для этого использовать какого то бота, если можно просто создать группу и добавить в нее нужных пользователей?

Comment: @ZxNuClear да мне только в бот нужно создать чат для троих